# Sort Vector<MyClass> on one of MyClass's data members?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl

I would like to create a class, call it `MyClass` which has three data members- a, b and c. I then wish to put many `MyClass` objects in to a `std::Vector<MyClass>` and then sort the Vector according to the a data members.

Is there an elegant way of doing this using the STL? I didn't want to re-invent the wheel and I am sure this can't be a first. In Java I guess I would use a `Comparator`.

Comment: You just need to implement `operator<()`

Comment: @RetiredNinja  myvector.Sort() isn't going to know anything about operator<() surely?

Comment: There is no `myvector.Sort()` unless you're not using a `std::vector`

Comment: @user997112: It doesn't need to "know about it"; the way C++ works is that the operator will just simply be found. Remember, the standard library code is in user space, so it's bound by all the same rules as your own code. If a matching `operator<` exists in scope, it'll be used; doesn't matter that the person who wrote `std::vector` for your platform is unaware that you'd do that.

Comment: @user997112: _(continued)_ Consider how the person who writes `template <typename T> void foo(T t) { bar(t); }` doesn't need to know anything about which overloads are available for `bar`. If there is one, it'll be used. If there are none, you will get an overload resolution failure error. If there are multiple, you will get an ambiguity error. The person who wrote the library does not care -- it is up to you to provide that implementation, and once you do everything works well.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I meant- I didnt realise sort() just looks at the < operator....

Comment: @user997112: Okay. Well, [it does](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). :) (_The documentation is your friend..._)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
bool operator < (MyClass const& lhs, MyClass const& rhs)
{
    return lhs.a < rhs.a;
}
```

std::sort requires the value_type of the iterators to be less-than comparable, or in more technical terms, they must form a strict weak ordering. Given the code above, you should now be able to sort it like any other type:

```
std::sort(std::begin(my_classes), std::end(my_classes));
```

assuming my_classes is a std::vector.

Comment: Thanks for this precise answer

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 5):

There are 3 ways to do this using `std::sort`.

- Implement an `operator<` function in the `MyClass` class.
- Pass a function to `sort` that takes two `const &MyClass` reference parameters and returns `bool` `true` when the first object is less than the second.
- Pass a functor object (a class that implements `operator()`) to `sort`; as with the stand-alone function, `operator()` should take two `const &MyClass` parameters and return a `bool`. Since the object can have internal state, you can use it to dynamically determine which field to sort on for example, or whether the sort should be ascending or descending.

First option:

```
bool MyClass::operator<(const MyClass &rhs)
{
    return a < rhs.a;
}

std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Second option:

```
bool CompareMyClass(const MyClass &lhs, const MyClass &rhs)
{
    return lhs.a < rhs.a; // this function will need to be declared friend if a is private
}

std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), CompareMyClass);
```

Third option:

```
struct MyFunctor
{
    bool operator()(const MyClass &lhs, const MyClass &rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.a < rhs.a;
    }
};

std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), MyFunctor());
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a comparator in the Java sense (i.e. an external comparison function which is not part of the class definition), create a functor:

```
struct {
    bool operator()(const MyClass& c1, const MyClass& c2) {
        return c1.a < c2.a;
    }
} my_comparator;
```

and pass it into `std::sort`:

```
std::sort(std::begin(my_classes), std::end(my_classes), my_comparator);
```

Alternatively, if on C++11, use a lambda:

```
std::sort(my_classes.begin(), my_classes.end(), [](const MyClass& c1, const MyClass& c2) {
    return c1.a < c2.a;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can code a compare function and use STL set
To code a comparison implement like this :

```
bool operator<(MyClass other) const
{
    return (expression);
}
```

Comment: Or do the same thing but indent it properly.